# identifying a website feature

Tags: html, css

Sorry for the vague title.

I am trying to identify a feature that I have been seeing on lots of websites lately.

It is some type of animation that freelancers use when they say something like "projects worked on" or "hours spent coding" then there will be a counter that starts from 0 then increases to a number, say 64, and also a circle may start to form or some kind of load bar that accompanies the rise in number.

I'm very sorry if this question is in the wrong place, I would be very happy if somebody could advise where I could find more information about this subject.

and example is at jamesdowen .com

Comment: You are trying to identify the feature name or a library to do some kind of preloading animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you're looking for: http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/

Though I must say, I don't recommend it to have on your portfolio as it shows vague stats. Graphs are good to use if you can use it to show correctly.

Comment: im only going to use it for vague stats anyway, its not for anything important. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for jQuery Knob
Google it, or just start here: http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/